# Override variables in nested module

Tags: sass

Tried many different ways but doesn't seem to work. Hoping someone can shed some light on this

This is what I'm trying to achieve and `_variable.scss` / `_base.scss` are coming from a library so I can't modify them

```
_variables.scss
$color: red !default;

_base.scss
@use 'variable' as base-variable;
.test {
  color: base-variable.$color;
}

my-component.scss
@use '_base'; // I want to modify the color in this file, how should it be done?

**expected output
.test {
  color: **another color**;
}
```

Comment: You are not able to use variable to another CSS file. You can only overwrite the CSS not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, you can override the whole imported module.

**my-component**

```
@use 'variable' as base-variable with (
  $color: 'another-color'
);
@use '_base'
```